About the iterator protocol
Why in Python is the iterator exhaustion fixed by calling StopIteration, and not by implementing the IsDone() method on the iterator, as written in GoF Design Patterns?
Raising an exception is still a rather expensive operation.

Not sure exceptions are expensive anymore just FYI: https://www.frameworktraining.co.uk/news-insights/python-3-11-is-here/#:~:text=As%20part%20of%20this%20change,or%20Exception%20is%20not%20raised.

next() on an exhausted iterator should raise an exception, yes?

Trying code that doesn't raise an exception has been nearly zero-cost for a very long time. The cost of a single StopIteration exception, amortized over the length of an non-trivial iteration, is virtually negligible.
